# Retrieve Drupal Commerce order history

Tags: commerce

Is it possible to retrieve a user's order history programatically?

Ideally, I would be able to user the user's profile ID to then load multiple past orders.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes you can use the [`commerce_order_load_multiple()`](http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions!commerce!modules!order!commerce_order.module/function/commerce_order_load_multiple/7) function and take advantage of the `$conditions` parameter, e.g.

```
$orders = commerce_order_load_multiple(array(), array('uid' => $user_id));
```